# C# Search function, how to check if any results?

Tags: c#, search

ive made a search function for my C# console app, and it works just great!
But when i search for a product that does not exist, it just returns blank.. i would like to test if there are actually any hits, and if not, write it out to the user, and if there are hits, show the result like normal.

My search function:

```
public List<Product> SearchProduct(string searchresult)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = Database.openConnection();
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductName Like @ProductName);", conn);
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", "%" + searchresult + "%");
                using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-10} {3,-15} {4,-10}", "ID:", "Produkt:", "Antal:", "SubKategori:", "Sidst redigeret af:\n");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Checking if reader has a value.. 
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.ToString()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No product with that criteria..\n");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-10} {3,-15} {4,-10}", 
                    reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2), reader.GetInt32(3), reader.GetInt32(4));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nTryk vilkårlig tast for at returnere");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                conn.Close();
            }
            return products;
        }
```

Comment: `reader.Read()` returns `false` if there aren't any more rows. Of course, if it's the first time you call it then it returns `false` if there aren't any rows period.

Comment: But how to check it after getting the rows?

Comment: @MichaelAggerholm You are not populating your products-list, after you have implemented that, it is really easy to just check what is products.count

Comment: Thank you Esko. i will give it a go with count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to a `do`/`while` and check the result for the initial `reader.Read()` before entering the loop:

```
bool canRead = reader.Read();
if (canRead)
{
    do
    {
        // Checking if reader has a value.. 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.ToString()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No product with that criteria..\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-10} {3,-15} {4,-10}", 
        reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2), reader.GetInt32(3), reader.GetInt32(4));
    }
    while (canRead = reader.Read());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
}
```

Alternatively, populate your `products` list and check `products.Count` once the loop is complete (as per Esko's comment).